# How to create a 10bit eglImage？How to use 10bit on OpengL？

Tags: opengl-es, yuv, dma

- I can create 8bit Yuv eglImage and use it normally. But the NDK doesn't seem to support the 10bit P010. I can't find AHARDWAREBUFFER_FORMAT_YCbCr_P010 defined in the latest NDK version.
- There is also no description of AHARDWAREBUFFER_FORMAT_YCbCr_P010 on the document. [AHardwareBuffer](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/a-hardware-buffer)
- Maybe the current device doesn't support 10bit?
  [TEST(AHardwareBufferTest, PlanarLockAndUnlockYuvP010Succeed)](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/master/tests/tests/nativehardware/jni/AHardwareBufferTest.cpp)
- How can I use 10bit YUV P010 data on Eglimage and opengL?
- I did some research, but nothing good came of it.
- Below is my example of creating, welcome to comment and direction.

```
int ret = 0;
AHardwareBuffer_Desc desc { };
{
    desc.width = (uint32_t)m_nWidth;
    desc.height = (uint32_t)m_nHeight;
    desc.usage = AHARDWAREBUFFER_USAGE_CPU_READ_OFTEN | AHARDWAREBUFFER_USAGE_CPU_WRITE_NEVER
                 | AHARDWAREBUFFER_USAGE_GPU_COLOR_OUTPUT | AHARDWAREBUFFER_USAGE_GPU_SAMPLED_IMAGE;

    /**
     * YUV P010 format.
     * Must have an even width and height. Can be accessed in OpenGL
     * shaders through an external sampler. Does not support mip-maps
     * cube-maps or multi-layered textures.
     */
//            AHARDWAREBUFFER_FORMAT_YCbCr_P010               = 0x36,
    desc.format = AHARDWAREBUFFER_FORMAT_Y8Cb8Cr8_420;
    desc.layers = 1;

    ret = AHardwareBuffer_isSupported(&desc);
    printf("AHardwareBuffer_isSupported: %d", ret);
}
AHardwareBuffer *dstHBuf = nullptr;
{
    ret = AHardwareBuffer_allocate(&desc, &dstHBuf);
    AHardwareBuffer_describe(dstHBuf, &desc);
}


auto eglDisplay = eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY);//sCurEnv.GetDisplay();
EGLClientBuffer dst_cbuf = eglGetNativeClientBufferANDROID(dstHBuf);
EGLint attrs[] = { EGL_IMAGE_PRESERVED_KHR, EGL_TRUE, EGL_NONE};
EGLImageKHR egl_image = eglCreateImageKHR(eglDisplay, EGL_NO_CONTEXT,
                                      EGL_NATIVE_BUFFER_ANDROID, dst_cbuf, attrs);
if (egl_image == EGL_NO_IMAGE_KHR) {
    EGLint error = eglGetError();
    printf("error creating EGLImage: %#x", error);
}


GLuint nSrcTexture = 0;
glGenTextures(1, &nSrcTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, nSrcTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, nSrcTexture);
glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES(GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, egl_image);
```

Comment: When I force desc.format = 0x36, AHardwareBuffer_isSupported returns no support

Answer (score 0):

- How can I use 10bit YUV P010 data on opengL?

  1. Use GL_RGBA16UI to read 10bit data in accordance with 16bit.
  2. Convert P010 to RGB10A2 and then use GL_RGB10_A2.

Comment: Note: GL_NEAREST should be used to create the texture, otherwise the sample will not get the correct data.